# マイクラMOD作成のためのForgeセットアップがうまくできない: Task 'setupDecompWorkspace' not found in root project

Tags: java

マイクラのMODを作ってるんですがforgeのセットアップがうまくできません
↓コマンドプロント

```
C:\Users\81704\OneDrive\デスクトップ\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859-mdk (1)>gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

> Configure project :
New Dep: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2859_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'setupDecompWorkspace' not found in root project 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859-mdk (1)'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGm8OumDf1I

↑の動画のとおりに作っています原因わかる方いたら教えてくださいお願いします

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　もし他のサイトにも投稿なさっている場合は、そのことを明確にしておきたいです。こちらの FAQ をご覧ください: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110

Answer (score 2):

Mdk のセットアップのために `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` を実行するのは古い Forge のための手段です。現在では新しい方法が使われているため実装が削除されており `Task 'setupDecompWorkspace' not found`、つまり `setupDecompWorkspace` が見つからないというエラーが出ています。

正しいやり方は、同梱されている README.txt に英語で書かれています。

> Step 2: You're left with a choice.
> If you prefer to use Eclipse:
>
> 1. Run the following command: "gradlew genEclipseRuns" (./gradlew genEclipseRuns if you are on Mac/Linux)
>
> （中略）
>
> If you prefer to use IntelliJ:
>
> 1. Open IDEA, and import project.

つまり、Eclipse を使っているのであれば `gradlew genEclipseRuns` を実行し、IntelliJ を使っているのであればそのままプロジェクトをインポートしてください。

エラーメッセージのうちの大事そうな部分、今回であれば `Task 'setupDecompWorkspace' not found in root project` で検索すると同じようなことで困って解決している様子がいくつか出てくるので、やり方の参考にしてみてください。また、README.txt や http://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/ などの公式ドキュメントを読むことも助けになるはずです。